# Does the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 .NET Core library support RedHat SSO with SAML 2.0 or has anyone gotten it to work?

Tags: .net-core, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2, redhat-sso

Looking for the easiest way to authenticate with RedHat SSO SAML 2.0 (not OpenId) in a .NET Core application.  I stumbled upon the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library and was wondering if anyone has gotten this to work before struggling with an endless array of trial-and-error scenarios.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question- yes it does seem to work.  The Startup.cs given in the sample code mostly works as-is, except SAML wants the Issuer to be the client ID in RedHat SSO and you need to fill in your AssertionConsumerServiceUrl in the redirect binding on the login.